# Installer conditionally picking up files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building a Wix installer and I need two separate versions of said installer.  One that picks up the latest development build of the project and one that picks up the latest release build. Currently my fragment looks like this:

```
<Property Id="Program.ReleaseBuild" Value="0" />
<?define ReleaseBuild = [Program.ReleaseBuild]?>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="InstallFolder">
        <Component Id="TheExe" Guid="GUID_GOES_HERE">
            <?if $(var.ReleaseBuild) = 1?>
            <File Id="ProjectExe" Source="(Rel Project Path)/program.exe" />
            <?else?>
            <File Id="ProjectExe" Source="(Dev Project Path)/program.exe" />
            <?endif?>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

And I have a transform on the msi that transforms the file after build. But the problem is that the file is picked up on compile time not install time, so both version of the installer end up having the same file contained in them. Any idea how I can conditionally grab a dev file or a rel file in the same wix project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create installation packages based on build quality (debug *versus* release), you can use two product configuration and select the source based on it. This way, you can run msbuild twice, one for each configuration. I don't understand the purpose of the transform you mentioned.

So here are steps you could take to accomplish this:

1. Create an empty solution.
2. Add your wixproj to it.
3. Add your csproj to it.
4. Add a reference of the csproj to the wixproj.
5. Modify your `File[Source]` to use the project reference, this way:

```
<File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" Id="ProjectExe" />
```

The `$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)` will automatically get the exe from the correct path.

6. Create a batch file to run the msbuild twice, one for each configuration, with the following commands:

```
C:\> msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
C:\> msbuild mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

The result will be two installation packages, one for each configuration.